# How to convert Decimal Time to ISO8601 formatted time

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, aura

I have time field in my object, which I'm using in my lightning:input field to display.
The value which I'm getting is in Decimal Time and to pre populate that value in lightning:input time type, I need to convert it into ISO8601 format. 
Is there any way to convert it in that format, so that it prepopulate in lightning:input

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean epoch time (or [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)), which specifies the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. JavaScript has an easy method for doing this: the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor, followed by the [Date.toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method.

```
var isoTime = new Date(unixTime).toISOString();
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but the format is in date time also in string

Comment: @sfdc You could split the string on `T` and use the second half to get just the time.

Comment: Thanks it works